# Удаление фрагмента в круглых скобках, учитывая, что они могут быть вложенными

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Дано задание: "Удалить из текста все фрагменты в круглых скобках (и сами скобки). Учесть, что скобки могут быть вложенными".

У меня есть данное решение:

```
String str = textArea1.getText();
str = str.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\) ?", "");
```

Оно прекрасно справляется с удалением текста в скобках, но не работает, когда речь идёт о вложенных.
Т.е в примере "Это текстовая строка (пример (вложенная скобка))" на выходе я получаю "Это текстовая строка )".

Comment: `.*?` - вопросительный знак уменьшает жадность выражения, поэтому останавливается на первой закрывающей скобке. Без вопросительного знака `.*` будет захватывать по максимуму.

Comment: В данном случае будет некорректно работать при наличии нескольких скобок. Например из "A (B) C (D)" мы получим "A".

Comment: В условии задачи нет же условия "с помощью регулярных выражений"? Стоит отметить, что регулярные выражения не являются универсальным средством от всего. Может им эта задача не по зубам в принципе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str = "Это текстовая строка (пример (вложенная скобка))";
        String regex = "\\s*\\([^()]*\\)";
        String tmp = "";
        do {
            tmp = str;
            str = str.replaceAll(regex, "");
        } while (!str.equals(tmp));
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/26Y2vM).

**Подробности**

- `\s*\([^()]*\)` находит ноль и более пробельных символов, `(`, ноль и более символов, отличных от круглых скобок, `)`
- `tmp` хранит предыдущее значение `str`
- пока `str` не равно `tmp`, происходит удаление найденных подстрок и данной строки.